# Kinect windows sdk 1.5 missing references

Tags: kinect

I'm a new comer to the kinect environment, and i was trying to modify some classes but couldn't find them,
SkeletonData skeleton;
Dictionary jointMap;
The SkeletonData and Joint ID is not found as references
what i'm trying to do is to apply this example:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-3EQ6xcFM8&feature=related
and this is the source code used for the modification but i dont know where to put it to get it working
http://codepaste.net/8j3pef

i need to display the angles of each joint of the skeleton so if anyone could help me or send me a project doing this for only one joint and then i'll apply on the other
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the API's have changed and you will need to migrate your code.

`SkeletonData` is now `Skeleton`.

`JointID` is now `Joint`.

See: http://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/k4w-code-migration-from-beta2-to-v1-0-managed/

Scroll down to see [Skeleton API Changes](http://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/k4w-details-of-api-changes-from-beta2-to-v1-managed/#skeletons)

I don't have a project for you, sorry.

Comment: Config doesn't look like it comes from Kinect. Your code snippet only uses it on line 638 to check whether to draw wireframe or not. Just reimplement this and adjust to your needs.

Comment: Actually `JointID` is now `JointType`, `Joint` is still `Joint`